# Using Serilog with MvvmCross

Tags: xamarin, logging, mvvmcross, serilog

I have this code in Setup.cs file

```
      protected override MvxLogProviderType GetDefaultLogProviderType() =>                                                  
                                                 MvxLogProviderType.Serilog;

      protected override IMvxLogProvider CreateLogProvider()
      {
          Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
            .WriteTo.Logger(config => config
                .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
                .WriteTo.File("C:\\log.txt"))
            .CreateLogger();
        return base.CreateLogProvider();
    }
```

In the ViewModel I have : private readonly IMvxLog _log initialized through IoC.

When I call _log.Error("Some error") nothing is written in log.txt file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that the logger writes in the context of the device/emulator/simulator that you are testing with. So `C:\\log.txt` would mean it is trying to write to that directory on the device.

**Android - File logging**

For Android you could make use of the external files directory as that does not require runtime permissions and can easily be accessed via a file explore or adb. The location would be something like `<storage_root>\Android\data\<App_Name>\files`.

```
protected override IMvxLogProvider CreateLogProvider()
{
    var externalFolder = Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(null).AbsolutePath;
    var path = Path.Combine(externalFolder, "log.txt");

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
        .WriteTo.Logger(config => config
            .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
            .WriteTo.File(path))
        .CreateLogger();
    return base.CreateLogProvider();
}
```

[image: Android_serilog]

**iOS - File logging**

For iOS you could make use of the MyDocument directory of the app. You can then access the `log.txt` on a Mac via the simulator. The location would be something like `Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<device_id>/data/Containers/Data/Application/<app_id>/Documents`.

```
protected override IMvxLogProvider CreateLogProvider()
{
    var docFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    var path = Path.Combine(docFolder, "log.txt");

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
        .WriteTo.Logger(config => config
            .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
            .WriteTo.File(path))
        .CreateLogger();
    return base.CreateLogProvider();
}
```

[image: iOS serilog]